# how to schedule this logstash configuration file to run in every 1 minute?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

## Problems:

**1)** How to run this configuration file run in every 1 minute.
(I try using schedule => "* * * * *"  and sincedb_write_interval => "60 sec")

**2)** How to keep count of lines accepting if stmt
(i used count++ but didn't work)

---

Here is my configuration file:

---

```
 input
 {
 generator { count => 1 }

      file 
    {
        path => "C:/ELK-Stack/log files/SAPInterface.log"
start_position => "beginning"
sincedb_path => "C:\ELK-Stack\LG\logstash\data\plugins\inputs\file\.sincedb"
sincedb_write_interval => "60 sec"
      }
 }    
filter 
{
    grok
{
  match => [
      "message",
      "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logsimestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:type}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ERROR}\]%{SPACE}%{INT:INT}:%{WORD:type2}%{SPACE}%{WORD:type3}%{SPACE}%{WORD:type4}"
    ]

    }
 if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] 
    {
            drop { }
        }

 if "2000023" in [INT]
{
 mutate 
    {
      add_tag => ["countthetimes"]
count++
}
}


 }
output
 {

     stdout
 {
codec => json_lines
}

elasticsearch 
{
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "cs_00000000000000"   
  }
}
```

---

## Expected output

The expected output is to give count and run this configure file every minute automatically.

Comment: I don't understand why you want this configuration to run "once every minute". Once logstash has started, the file input plugin just "Stream events from files, normally by tailing them". And the sincedb is a file that saves what part of which file had been read.

Comment: ok yeah, I got it. there is no need for that..thank u

Comment: what my requirement is:- I need to generate the alert whenever I encounter pattern in the log file it should generate alert + it should stop there itself(no need to parse whole log file), and if I correct that error from log it should be immediately reflected back to kibana and then again it starts parsing the rest of the file.

Comment: I don't think that's doable with logstash. At least _I_ don't see how to do it.

Comment: can you please recommend how to achieve that using ELK stash

Comment: can I give simple declare 1 variable say x, and use if statement to obtain if x>1, then print yes?

Comment: I don't know this is possible here or not if yes can u help

Comment: Have one more query. I can see the data in the discovery panel for my mapping like below 

"businessdate:2019-04-25T18:30:00.000Z" But i want to visualize this only "2019-04-25" in Kibana. How can I achieve this? By the way I am fetching this data from the DB using config file and the DB the besiness date field Type is long.